# add data back to text field

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to populate a `<input />` from the database using AJAX, but can only get the data testing in a `<textarea>` or `<span>`.

My AJAX code

```
$('#part_number').on('change', function() {

    var part_number = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?PHP echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'description', part_number: part_number },
        success: function(data) {

            $('#description').val( data );

        }
    });

});
```

My input field

`<input id="description" value="" />`

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_description' , 'description');  //ajax parameter action
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_description','description');
    function description(){
       $part_number = $_POST['part_number']; //id

       global $wpdb;
       $stock = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM _cif_inventory_table WHERE part_number = '$part_number'");
           foreach ( $stock as $item ) {
             echo $item->Description;
           }

      die();
}
```

I couldn't find anything here or google

**EDIT** This is in a loop so there are 20 lines, but the only one that works is the first one, what did I do wrong?

```
<?PHP
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
        ?>
            <div id="lines" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><span id="row_number"><?PHP if ( $i < 10 ){ echo "0".$i;}else{echo $i;} ?></span></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080">
                    <select id="part_number" style="border:0px;">
                        <option value="None Selected"></option>
                        <?PHP
                            $partNumbers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM _cif_inventory_table;");
                                foreach ($partNumbers as $partNumber) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$partNumber->part_number.'">'.$partNumber->part_number.'</option>';
                                }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input size="5" maxlength="5" id="quantity" value="" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input size="75" id="description" value="" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input id="unitPrice" value="" /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #808080"><input id="amount" value="" /></div>
            </div><!-- end .row -->
        <?PHP
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? Note that you have an SQL injection attack in your code, since you never check that `part_number` is actually a number, and not an SQL statement. Additionally, what do you mean by `"can only get the data testing in a textarea or a span?"` I presume you're already aware that `html` sets the inner HTML of elements, but `input` elements don't have inner HTML

Comment: part_number isn't really a number it is a string. Can you give examples of REST I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: You use `.val()` for `input`, not `.html()` ... e.g. like this `$('#description').val( data );`

Comment: @LGSon I feel dumb! Thank You! this was actually my first attempt at AJAX! You made my day

Comment: @LGSon Actually maybe you can help with something else I have this input in a for loop and I can only get the first row to actually do anything?

Comment: I don't know PHP. Add the tag to your tags list, and update your question to focus on that part, now when the assignment is solved.

Comment: Avoid adding different questions to a post, as people tend not to go back to them. If you create a new question, make sure you paste in your PHP and the rendered code from the element inspector.

Comment: @bckelley can you replace everything in your AJAX with some static HTML so it always returns the same thing? That should eliminate the PHP from your question

Comment: Technically @LGSon answered my initial question first so he is the accepted answer!

Comment: @bckelley Apologize for the "accept her answer" thing. But once again, "*this input in a for loop and I can only get the first row to actually do anything*" - that's because you're using the same ID on the elements in all the 20 rows generated via that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fill in the value attribute of the input, so you need to use `.val()`:

`$('#description').val( data );`